# I want to lock my cell cells (E3:AH17) daily after 11:00 am base on cell date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[how to lock cell autometicly base on cell data & and time everyday?]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PQTpr9tes5_7c963nV_c0BSOdemYD6Vpyd1SB1elANE/edit#gid=1118459963

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A possible solution for this is to use a time based trigger in Apps Script which will lock the cells you want.

You should start by writing a script similar to this:

```
function lockCells() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS_ID").getSheetByName("Attendance1");
  let protection = sheet.getRange(3, 5, 15, 30).protect(); // CORRESPONDS TO E3:AH17
  let editors = protection.getEditors();
  protection.removeEditors(editors)
}

function timeTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('lockCells')
    .timeBased()
    .atHour(11)
    .create();
}
```

The code above consists in the two functions:

- `lockCells` - which is used to protect the range by retrieving the editors and then removing them;
- `timeTrigger` - which will trigger the `lockCells` function every day at 11:00.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Range Class - protect()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect);
- [Apps Script Protection Class - getEditors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection.html#geteditors);
- [Apps Script Protection Class - removeEditors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection.html#removeeditorsemailaddresses);
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: Dear "ale13", Thank you so much for your reply and your precious time.But i don't have any knowled about coding or any tigger things.thats why i have shared a link which can lead you to the actual sheet ,and you can write code there for me.will that be too much to ask? if you can do that for me,it will be so healpful. Thanks in advance.